# Specific values in the string change with string[] array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a big string array and string like that:

```
    string[] array = new string[3264];
    array = {"00:00:45,104","00:01:04,094","01:43:24,001"....};
    string str = "00:00:13,614 /n rose /n 00:01:14,001...",
```

I have same amount of time in string and array. I want to change these values. For example new string must be:

```
str = "00:00:45,104 /n rose /n 00:01:04,094 ...";
```

I mean times change for array's element. I think i can find times in string:

```
var mL = Regex.Matches(subtitle, @"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

But I don't know how can I change them.

Comment: where `rose` came from? if you put them in another array too you can achieve what you want pretty easy.

Comment: this means string like subtitle. I just want to change times. words and others must be stay.

Comment: ok so you should specify in your question that you are trying to change a subtitle file. what format is it? `.sub` ?

Comment: i didn't specify so much because i thought my problem not my all code so i didn't want to tire you. I will edit in 2 min.

Comment: i tried but can't explain myself but thanks you @M.kazemAkhgary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `Regex.Replace`, like this:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "00:00:45,104","00:01:04,094","01:43:24,001"};
string str = "00:00:13,614 /n rose /n 00:01:14,001";
int i = 0;
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)", m => array[i++]);
```

The replace takes each match and calls the lambda function to get the string it should be replaced with.  So the lambda function is just returning the next value in your array.

Comment: That's it. Thanks you so much.